# `git stash apply --index` fails with `error: No valid patches in input` on one machine

Tags: git, git-stash

When I try to pop/apply a simple stash with `--index` that includes files from the index/staging area, I get the following output:

```
$ git stash apply --index   
error: No valid patches in input (allow with "--allow-empty")
error: conflicts in index. Try without --index.
```

This only happens on my machine (git version 2.43.0, arch linux+zsh). I cannot reproduce it on another machine.

I tried disabling `autocrlf`, but it does not solve the problem.

This does not happen if I omit `--index`.

Comment: a. inspect `stash` with a history viewer (for example `gitk stash`, or run `git log --oneline --graph stash` and see what commits should be compared) to figure out what patches should be applied ; b. perhaps the index part is already part of the committed changes on your new HEAD, have you tried running `git stash apply` (without `--index`) as suggested ?

Comment: @LeGEC: This happens only with `--index` which I am trying to use.  I will update the question.  I can't find something useful or related using `git log` or `gitk`

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I had a setting that messed it up:

```
git config pager.stash="less -FRX"
```

I will report this as a bug :-)

Comment: do you mean: the presence of this setting would prevent `git stash apply --index`  from working properly ??

Comment: @LeGEC: exactly.